# node-red. Read a node status every 1 second

Tags: node-red

Is it possible to write a statement in function node to read a node status(for mqtt)?

What I want is to use a timestamp at the input of the function to trigger read mqtt status for every second. I know there is a "status" node, that certainly doesn't work the way I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,

But you could use the `status` node to set a variable in the [context](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/context) which you can then read in a separate flow once every second.

[image]

This monitors the satatus of the MQTT-in node and sets `global.mqttState`. The inject node fires and reads the state back in.

Comment: It works. I used 1 change node. I changed it "move msg.status.text to global.mqttState" and inject node to global.mqttState linked to for example a debug node and I get the result I needed. Thanks!